# Is semnatic entailing a one to one representation of a truth table?

Tags: logic

Lets say I have proposition A and proposition B and I have to consider whether A⊨B

I can find some assignment of truth values to the variables in A which will give the whole proposition a truth value, but that same assignment will give a false assignment to B and therefore I have proven A does not semantically entail B (A!⊨B).

However, my question is whether if I find an assignment that assigns a total truth value to B but a total false value to A, is that an appropriate proof that A does not semantically entail B?

[Problem in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPM0B.png)

So for example, finding an assignment for the left-hand side that is all F and the right-hand side is T, is that as valid as finding an assignment that is F for the right side and T for the left side?

Thank you for the help

Comment: "*So for example, finding an assignment for the left-hand side that is all F and the right-hand side is T,*" I can't figure out whether you mean that the left side is a contradiction (i.e., all assignments for the left side are F), or whether you mean that there exists a particular assignment such that the left side('s main connective) is F and the right side's main connective is T.     If the former, then yes A doesn't semantically entail B. If the latter, then no, it doesn't necessarily mean that  A doesn't semantically entail B.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by the question in your title, but the bicondition that a semantic entailment holds if and only if there is no row in the truth table which has all premises T and the conclusion F holds 1:1. If under a particular assignment all premises are false, then this counts positively towards the entailment, because then it is not a counter-assignment that validates the premises and invalidates the conclusion. If the left-hand side is all F's, i.e. there is no assignment under which all premises are true to begin with, then in particular there is no assignment under which all premises are true and the conclusion false, so the entailment holds.